# Wireless bridge settings

Tags: networking, bridge, wifi

Using two TP-Link WA-5210G, I am trying to create a network bridge between two networks, netA and netB. I want to share my internet connection from netA to netB, using the AP from netB.

```
netA :: Wireless ADSL modem / router : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP disabled
        Wireless AP in client mode, LAN connected with ADSL router @ 192.168.1.254

netB :: Wireless AP in AP mode : 192.168.1.253
        DHCP disabled
        Other wireless clients with static manual IP addresses
```

For default gateway and DNS at the clients in netB I set the IP of the modem / router, 192.168.1.1, and I have confirmed that a client can ping the router. But still no internet. What remains to be done?

Comment: Have you logged into netA and pinged any IP/domain on the internet?

Comment: I send this message from netA right now, netA has internet access. But when I try to ping from my computer in netA to say www.google.com, I get a request timeout although the DNS resolution works fine. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used 802.11g for the wireless link. I switched to 802.11b and the connection is as stable as rock. No packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

Either connect the netA and netB devices with a physical cable or the netB device needs to be set to be a client of netA (either directly in client mode or via an extend-a-network mode or however TP-Link specifies it).

Comment: Physical cable is not an option, the two networks are about 7 km away! netB in client mode was the initial *working* configuration but I had to change it. Why doesn't it work now, especially when it can find the router?

Comment: Because the two AP's are running independently of one another - there's no notion of how to bridge a packet from one to the other.  One of the devices works as an AP, the other as a client.

Comment: I still don't get it. What do you mean by saying "bridge a packet"? Since any device in the network connects to the router, the gateway and DNS settings should be enough. What if I add a static route to my router?